# What the difference between clearall() or cancelall() for local notifications in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, localnotification

As I see in the doc of local notifications, there is 2 functions for deleting the notifications ?

The first one clearall();

The second cancelall();

So what the different between them, what should I use batter than other ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with this Ionic plugin, but based on [the source code](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/blob/master/src/android/notification/Manager.java#L156), it looks like `clearAll()` removes only *triggered* notifications, while `cancelAll()` removes *all* of them.

Comment: Correct; relevant documentation: **[Clear](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/06.-Clear)**, **[Cancelation](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/07.-Cancelation)**